# How to show Menu Array in Razor View from appsettings.json in ASP.NET Core RazorPages

Tags: c#, json, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

How to show Menu Array in Razor View from appsettings.json in ASP.NET Core RazorPages, I stuck on here in few days. Anyone can give me a solution for this please?

```
public void OnGet()
{
    ViewData["Test"] = Test().AsEnumerable();
}

public class AppMenu
{
    public string MenuName { get; set; } // Module Name
    public List<AppMenu> MenuList { get; set; } = new List<AppMenu>();
}

public string Test()
{
    var apps = new List<AppMenu>();
    List<string[]> listMenus = new List<string[]>();
    var hpMenu = new[] { "xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx" };
    var vtMenu = new[] { "yyy", "yyy", "yyy", "yyy", "yyy" };
    var purAgr = new[] { "zzz", "zzz", "zzz" };
    var mainManu = new[] { "aaa", "aaa"};
    listMenus.Add(hpMenu);
    listMenus.Add(vtMenu);
    // listMenus.Add(hpMenu)
    foreach (var main in mainManu)
    {
        AppMenu appmainmenu = new AppMenu();
        appmainmenu.MenuName = main;
        apps.Add(appmainmenu);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i <= listMenus.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        List<AppMenu> lsmenu = new List<AppMenu>();
        foreach (var menustr in listMenus[i])
        {
            AppMenu appmenu = new AppMenu();
            appmenu.MenuName = menustr;
            if (menustr == "Purchase Agreement")
            {
                foreach (var it in purAgr)
                {
                    AppMenu purr = new AppMenu();
                    purr.MenuName = it;
                    appmenu.MenuList.Add(purr);
                }
            }
            lsmenu.Add(appmenu);
        }
        apps[i].MenuList = lsmenu;
    }
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(apps);
}
```

Anyone can help me show the menu please, somethings like this.
Index.cshtml (e.g)

```
@foreach (var test in ViewData["Test"])
{
    <p>@test</p>
}
```

Comment: How to use the Test() method in View.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, what exactly you are trying to do and why you are converting a JsonString to an enumerable.

If you need those classes in your view you can use them by defining a list of menues in your model:

```
public List<AppMenu> AppMenues;
public void OnGet()
{
    AppMenues = Test();
}
```

In your Test function you should simply return the List you are creating. I will use your function name, but you should really rename it:

```
public List<AppMenu> Test()
{
    var apps = new List<AppMenu>();
    //your filling logic
    return apps;
}
```

Now you can use it in your RazorPage:

```
@page
@model HomeModel
@{
    foreach (var i in Model.AppMenues)
    {
        <p>@i.MenuName</p>
    }
}
```

The name of your model should differ, if you are not on a page named home.

Comment: Can't only return apps without JsonConvert

Comment: Thank you for your example, now i can understand how to use the Test method.

Comment: but in the public string Test() change to public List<AppMenu> Test()

Comment: but even like this i also cant get the menulist

Comment: Could you try do explain the problem a bit more? What does not work exactly? Is the List empty? Is it not possible at all to use the model in your razor page?